# Storing emojis in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, collation

I'm new to MySQL database. I want to store emojis in my database. I already have data in my database, and I don't want to lose it.

I don't know the proper way of storing the utf8mb4 character-set using the MySQL console. Is there any way of doing that using mysql-administrator?

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";
+-------------------------+-----------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value                 |
+-------------------------+-----------------------+
| innodb_version          | 5.7.33                |
| protocol_version        | 10                    |
| slave_type_conversions  |                       |
| tls_version             | TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2 |
| version                 | 5.7.33-log            |

mysql> SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE 'character\_set\_%' OR 
Variable_name LIKE 'collation%';
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value              |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8               |
| character_set_connection | utf8               |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_filesystem | binary             |
| character_set_results    | utf8               |
| character_set_server     | utf8               |
| character_set_system     | utf8               |
| collation_connection     | utf8_general_ci    |
| collation_database       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
| collation_server         | utf8_general_ci    |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
10 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

I changed `my.cnf` file to

```
[client]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysqld]
character-set-client-handshake = FALSE
character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

It shows no error, but neither does it store the emojis - when enter emojis it shows as **?** this question mark.

I convert the `utf-8` encoding to `utf8mb4_general_ci`:

```
|--------------------------+--------------------|
| character_set_system     | utf8               |
|--------------------------+--------------------|
| collation_connection     | utf8mb4_general_ci |
| collation_database       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
| collation_server         | utf8_general_ci    |
|--------------------------+--------------------|
```

Comment: The connection matters not if the storage collation does not support 4-byte characters. If your database tables are all using some `latin` or `general` collation, you’re boned. These collations only support 1-byte characters (and sometimes 3-byte). This is why I asked the question.

Comment: @matigo can it be changed?

Comment: Its just software. **You** control the software. Yes, it can be changed so long as the effort is something worth investing in. The question i asked earlier was looking for a `CREATE` statement for the table(s), as this would determine if a change is necessary at all or if the problem is elsewhere in the stack. Modern software is built like a house of cards. When done right, it’s an amazing sight to behold. If just one spectator sneezes, though …

Comment: well as i described the full problem in stack overflow. i'm using django and my tables are created by models field by class based views

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for one of the tables where you need Emoji.  It probably says 'utf8' on the columns and/or default for the table.  The columns must be `utf8mb4`.

```
ALTER TABLE tbl CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;
```

Will blindly change all the columns to utf8mb4.  This is *probably* the action you need.

Also, the *connection* needs to specify utf8mb4.  Since I don't know what client you are using, I can't provide specific information.  If necessary, run this right after connection: `SET NAMES utf8mb4;`

Terminology:

- "character set", such as `utf8` or `utf8mb4` is the *encoding* for the characters.  This is where you are having trouble with storing Emoji.
- "collation" is the ordering, such as whether 'a' < 'b' and whether there is case folding to make 'a' = 'A'.  Collation may be important when comparing (`WHERE`) or sorting (`ORDER BY`).

Comment: I already tried these commands. I wil try again with these commands.

Comment: Thank you its working